# How to call a tkinter class as an object or in button click?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'll be short. I created a tkinter GUI, which I need to call as an object or a window that appears on button click.
code is:

```
class Test(Frame):

    def __init__(self,master = None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master =  master
        self.win()

    def win(self):
        self.pack()

        self.label = Label(self, text="hello World!").pack()
        self.quit = Button(self, text= "quit", command = self.master.destroy).pack()
```

the code works fine when I call the class in the same file. ie, by adding

```
root=Tk()
Test()
```

but I want it to be called at a button click, but outside in other gui.

**what I tried:**

1) applying the same `root = Tk()` as it is.

2) calling it in a class as object by: self.test = Test() and applying command self.test.win in the button.

**Problem:**'module' object is not callable.

code of other gui, where I want the button to call Test class and show gui of that class:

```
import Test
class Wtf(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.btn()
        self.test = Test()

    def btn(self):
        self.pack()

        self.test = Test()

        self.btn = Button(self, text = "Call", command = self.test.win).pack()

root=Tk()
app = Wtf(root)
```

Thanks in advance. Hope I defined as much as required.

**for those who did not understand**:all i'm trying to here is to link the class data to the button 'btn', so that when I press the button I could get the class Test gui displayed either in the same window root or a different window.

**please note:** i'm a newbie at python and this program might not make sence to you, but all i'm trying here is to call the class Test on a buttonclick of 'btn'.

Comment: `Button(self, text = "Call", command = self.test.win).pack()` returns `None`, so that's what is assigned to `self.quit` or `self.btn`.

Comment: i'm a newbie at python so all I was trying to do was displaying the gui of class test in the button btn

Comment: My [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55322467/355230) does that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but there are numerous problems with your code, some of which I already pointed-out in a comment.

The `'module' object is not callable` problem is because you have a module called `Test` which defines a class named `Test` inside it, so the problem can be avoided by using `Test.Test` when referring to the class.

Here are working versions of the main script and the `Test.py` module:

`main.py`:

```
from tkinter import *
import Test


class Wtf(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.test = Test.Test(self.master)
        self.btn = Button(self, text="Call", command=self.test.win)
        self.btn.pack()

root = k()
app = Wtf(root)
app.mainloop()
```

---

`Test.py`:

```
from tkinter import *

class Test(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack()

    def win(self):
        self.label = Label(self, text="Hello World!")
        self.label.pack()
        self.quit = Button(self, text= "quit", command=self.master.destroy)
        self.quit.pack()
```

---

**Update**

Based on your comment about what you really want to do, I've adapted the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7557028/355230) to the question [Switch between two frames in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546050/switch-between-two-frames-in-tkinter) to your needs:

`main.py`

```
import tkinter as tk
import Test


class App(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (Wtf, Test.Test):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("Wtf")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        """ Show a frame for the given page name. """
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()


class Wtf(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.parent =  parent
        self.controller = controller
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.test = Test.Test(self.parent, self.controller)
        self.btn = tk.Button(self, text="Call",
                             command=lambda: self.controller.show_frame("Test"))
        self.btn.pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

---

`Test.py`:

```
import tkinter as tk


class Test(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.parent =  parent
        self.controller = controller
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="Hello World!")
        self.label.pack()
        self.quit = tk.Button(self, text= "Quit", command=self.controller.destroy)
        self.quit.pack()
```

Comment: sir ! it is a great program. I did understand it easily.  I have changed it to control various buttons and provide more than 1 GUIs. the problem i'm occurring with it is that i'm no able to reverse it. to explain it more specifically, in this case the flow is from main to test but I want to add a back button in test which can take me back from test to main without exiting the main window.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know, in this version you can call a function in Test() class from the main class of the program.

After run the script click on Open button then click on Call and watch what happen.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

class Test(tk.Toplevel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()

        self.parent =  parent
        self.title("I'm a new toplevel.")
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):

        self.label = tk.Label(self, text=self.title()).pack()
        self.close_me = tk.Button(self, text= "Close me", command = self.on_close_me).pack()
        self.close_parent = tk.Button(self, text= "Close parent", command = self.on_close_parent).pack()

    def on_close_me(self):
        self.destroy()        

    def on_close_parent(self):
        self.parent.on_close()

    def callback(self):
        msg = "I come from parent toplevel"
        messagebox.showwarning(self.master.title(), msg, parent=self)




class App(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self,):

        super().__init__()

        self.master.title("Hello World")

        self.obj = None

        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):

        self.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1,)

        f = tk.Frame()

        w = tk.Frame()

        tk.Button(w, text="Open", command=self.callback).pack()
        tk.Button(w, text="Call", command=self.call_child_function).pack()
        tk.Button(w, text="Close", command=self.on_close).pack()

        f.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=0)
        w.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=0)

    def callback(self):
        self.obj = Test(self)

    def call_child_function(self):
        self.obj.callback()


    def on_close(self,evt=None):
        self.master.destroy()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: wow! it does work as per I request but this would be taking a hell lot time to understand. by the way thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure to have understood well the question, anyway look below.

Particularly to

> self.close_me = tk.Button(self, text= "Close me", command = self.on_close_me).pack()
>
> self.close_parent = tk.Button(self, text= "Close parent", command = self.on_close_parent).pack()

You can even put the class Test on another file and input it.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Test(tk.Toplevel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()

        self.parent =  parent
        self.title("I'm a new toplevel.")
        self.init_ui()
          
    def init_ui(self):

        self.label = tk.Label(self, text=self.title()).pack()
        self.close_me = tk.Button(self, text= "Close me", command = self.on_close_me).pack()
        self.close_parent = tk.Button(self, text= "Close parent", command = self.on_close_parent).pack()

    def on_close_me(self):
        self.destroy()        
    
    def on_close_parent(self):
        self.parent.on_close()
        
        
class App(tk.Frame):
   
    def __init__(self,):
        
        super().__init__()

        self.master.title("Hello World")

        self.init_ui()
          
    def init_ui(self):

        self.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1,)

        f = tk.Frame()

        w = tk.Frame()

        tk.Button(w, text="Open", command=self.callback).pack()
        tk.Button(w, text="Close", command=self.on_close).pack()

        f.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=0)
        w.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=0)
        

    def callback(self):
        obj = Test(self)
        
    def on_close(self,evt=None):
        self.master.destroy()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: `.pack()` returns `None`.